Spark RandomForestClassifier returns trees with exact same splits
I am running a random forest classifier for binary classification problem with 2 input features. When looking at the model I'm noticing that the generated trees are all the same (exact same splits).
Here the code I'm running:
// Set up Pipeline.
val stages = new mutable.ArrayBuffer[PipelineStage]()

// (1) assembler
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler
val colSelected = List("feature_1", "feature_2")
val assembler = new VectorAssembler()
  .setInputCols(colSelected.toArray)
  .setOutputCol("features")
stages += assembler

// (2) Identify categorical features using VectorIndexer.
//     Features with more than maxCategories values will be treated as continuous.
val featuresIndexer = new VectorIndexer()
  .setInputCol("features")
  .setOutputCol("indexedFeatures")
stages += featuresIndexer

val dt = new RandomForestClassifier()
  .setSubsamplingRate(value = .25)
  .setFeaturesCol("indexedFeatures")
  .setLabelCol("selected")
  .setNumTrees(50)

stages += dt
val pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(stages.toArray)

// Fit the Pipeline.
val pipelineModel = pipeline.fit(training)

// Get the trained Random Forest from the fitted PipelineModel.
val rfModel = pipelineModel.stages.last.asInstanceOf[RandomForestClassificationModel]
println(rfModel.toDebugString)

I haven't seen any significant pattern in the data except for the fact that the one feature is heavily duplicated (almost categorical) and the class imbalance is pretty heavy (96%/4%).
I'm struggling to understand if the boostrapping is working fine or not, is there anyone who has any hypotheses on what to look at?
